# pregmatch not seeing http://

Tags: php, regex, laravel, preg-match, regex-negation

I need to compare 3 different URLs, in order to that i need to make them identical like `example.com`
I've created a `preg_match()`. So far i've accomplished to make the urls to `example.com` when the url looks like : `http://www.example.com`, `http://www.example.com/foo` and `www.example.com`. The only issue what im getting is, when the url looks like: `http://example.com` it doesnt `preg_match` it.. I think it recognizes it as `'clean'` so it skips it. Can you guys tell me what im doing wrong?

My code looks like this :

```
$pattern = '/.*[\.\/]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.\w{2,3})\/.*/';
            $results = $reader->noHeading()->takeColumns(1)->toArray();

            $cleaned = array();
            for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++){
                if(preg_match($pattern,$results[$i][0],$cleaned[$i]) === 1){
                    echo "<pre>";
                    var_dump($cleaned[$i][1]);
                    echo "</pre>";
                } 
            }
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: That way lay dragons. You'll be much better off working with the `parse_url()` function, as described by @RyanTuosto.

Comment: Search about `parse_url`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a non regex solution:

```
$myurl = "http://example.com";
$raw_url = parse_url($myurl); 
$domain_only = str_replace ('www.','', $raw_url['host']); 
echo $domain_only;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

parse_url returns an array of URL components in this case you're looking for the host and can just replace www if it exists.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good working alternative. Will use this in the future, this isnt as hard as regex.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you change your pattern to:

```
$pattern = '/.*[\.\/]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.\w{2,3}).*/'
```

Comment: This did the trick, thank you! But what exactly did you change?

Comment: I've just removed checking for "/" after host name, because your url `http://example.com` doesn't have slash symbol after the host name

Comment: hey @Kulikov Sergey this pattern doesnt fix urls like: `array(2) { [0]=> string(80) "http://www.architectuurtourmaastricht.nl/architectuurtourmaastricht.nl/Home.html" [1]=> string(8) "Home.htm" }`
Can you please help me with this? Thanks

Comment: @Armando van Oeffelen, Try to use another pattern `$pattern = '/^([^:]+:\/\/)?(\w+\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.\w{2,3})/';` and change `var_dump($cleaned[$i][1]);` to `var_dump($cleaned[$i][3]);`